# Performing the same operation on multiple selectors, elegantly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

On the project I'm working on, I've been writing a little JavaScript object.  One of its behaviors involve removing any children in a series of classes, as such:

```
function Foo () {
    var $a = $('.a'),
        $b = $('.b'),
        // ...etc...
        $n = $('.n');

    $a.remove();
    $b.remove();
    // ...etc again...
    $n.remove();
}
```

While there are some ways to revise this to be more easily maintainable (putting the selectors into a single array springs instantly to mind), I'm wondering if there's any elegant way to perform the `.remove()` operation on a series of selectors, as such:

```
function FooPrime() {
    var selectors = [
        '.a',
        '.b',
        // ...
        '.n'
    ];

    // Perform remove on all given selectors?
    $(selectors).remove();
}
```

Thus, **Question**: What are some ways I could perform a single jQuery operation on a number of selectors?

**EDIT**: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sQWuy/24/) is a JSFiddle to show a cut-down version of the problem context.

Comment: I'd be curious of the context in which you are doing this, is it possible that these elements you are wishing to remove should share a class? Keep in mind elements can have multiple classes.

Comment: Is there any way to update your HTML to have a common class? Instead of trying to select them one by one, you could just use this common class to pick them all.

Comment: In this case, there is no way to condense any of this because each class has different top, left, and border properties.  The context, is a system that removes a tail from a callout prior to appending a new tail to a callout.

Comment: @AndrewGray: Can you post the HTML? There's probably a simpler way to do it.

Comment: @AndrewGray, you could leave the class for styling, and add another class for the elements you want to remove for whatever purpose. `class="c removeme"`, `class="b removeme"`... you could then call `$(".removeme").remove()`. Also, if we see your context, it is possible that the elements you wish to remove could be accessed by association.

Comment: @AndrewGray You could simply add a dummy class to group them in this case.

Comment: @Vega - I don't understand exactly what you mean.  If it helps any, these classes are defined using LESS, and indeed draw on a mixin that defines parts of these properties.  The classes in question are all drawing CSS triangles.

Comment: @AndrewGray [smerny comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18281100/performing-the-same-operation-on-multiple-selectors-elegantly?noredirect=1#comment26817558_18281100) is exactly what I meant. [Point's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18281105/297641) is nice, but using a common class is simpler unless you have any concern changing your HTML.

Comment: If, for some reason, you need to keep a reference to the variables (`$a`, `$b`,...`$n`), **and** perform something on all of them, you can use something like `$a.add($b).add($n).someMethod();`, but it can be annoying when you have many jQuery objects to "combine". Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/kskkc/

Comment: @Ian - I don't have to, all I have to do is operate on each selector, which the given answer lets me do.  For everyone else, I'm working on a JSFiddle to show a cut-down version of the context I'm working with.

Comment: Added fiddle with problem context.

Comment: @AndrewGray, check this http://jsfiddle.net/sQWuy/25/

Comment: @smerny - you should make your implementation an answer, that's a really neat and fast one.

Comment: @AndrewGray, added it - this is what I meant by "accessed by association". I also showed an example using an extra class... then I showed a complete refactor of your code, going from 53 to 17 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for showing your DOM, you should avoid making big lists of classes to select when you can add multiple classes to elements and create a specific class for the elements you want to target... or target via association to other elements. This would be a more clean and efficient way to do it.

---

**By association**

Basically for the selector I just have this:

```
$("#test-callout").find("div").not(".callout-main").remove();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sQWuy/25/)

This assumes that you do not have any other div's besides `.callout-main` and the target div in `test-callout`. If you do you can modify the selector chain a bit to compensate.

---

**By adding another class**

Your arrow creation code was like this:

```
function calculateArrow() {
    var arrowClass;
    if(pub.isLeft) {
        arrowClass = 'callout-arrow-left';   
    } else {
        arrowClass = 'callout-arrow-right';
    }

    pub.$callout.append('<div class="' + arrowClass + '"></div>');
}
```

Modify it to be like this:

```
function calculateArrow() {
    $arrow = $("<div>")
    .addClass("callout-arrow")
    .addClass(pub.isLeft ? "callout-arrow-left" : "callout-arrow-right");        
    pub.$callout.append($arrow);
}
```

Then your selector can be simply:

```
$("#test-callout").find(".callout-arrow").remove();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sQWuy/27/)

---

If you are interested in a complete refactor - I reduced your CalloutObject from 53 to 17 lines and it still works the same.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sQWuy/29/)

Answer (score 6):

You can separate the selectors with commas:

```
 $(selectors.join(',')).remove();
```

The comma has that purpose in straight ordinary CSS selector syntax.